# How can I translate keycodes from /dev/input/event* to ASCII in Embedded Linux?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, embedded, input, keyboard-event

I'm building an embedded linux image with yocto. I can see the keys coming in over /dev/input/event0. I can view them using `showkey -k` but not `showkey -a`. I've also tried with an ncurses program I found here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/keys.html which doesn't detect any key presses at all.

Interestingly enough, if I'm running these programs over a terminal(e.g. minicom), `showkey -k`, `showkey -a` and the ncurses program all work as expected. So if I had to guess, it's as though linux has no problem detecting the events, it just doesn't realize it's a keyboard or is missing something required to convert key codes to ascii.